# Snap Failed to load modules that should be there

Tags: snap

I'm trying to create a snap for Dolphin-emu and it builds okay? but when trying to run Dolphin I get some errors that it failed to load modules, even though they are included in the .yaml

```
$ dolphin-emu-stable
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

(dolphin-emu:24601): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory

This likely means that your installation is broken.
Try running the command
  gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache
to make things work again for the time being.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here is the .yaml file

```
name: dolphin-emu-stable
version: 5.0
summary: Dolphin Emulator
description: Dolphin is a Nintendo Wii and Gamecube emulator

confinement: devmode

apps:
    dolphin-emu-stable:
        command: dolphin-emu
        plugs: [X11, network, network-bind, home, opengl, pulseaudio]

parts:
   dolphin-emu-stable:
       source: https://github.com/dolphin-emu/dolphin/archive/5.0.tar.gz
       plugin: cmake
      build-packages:
          - git
            - pkg-config
            - gcc
            - libwxbase3.0-dev
            - libwxgtk3.0-dev
            - libgtk2.0-dev
            - libxext-dev
            - libreadline-dev
            - libgl1-mesa-dev
            - libevdev-dev
            - libudev-dev
            - libpulse-dev
            - libbluetooth-dev
            - libxrandr-dev
            - libatk-bridge2.0-dev
            - libatk-bridge2.0-0
            - libgail-3-0
            - libgail-common
            - libgail18
            - libcanberra-gtk3-module
            - libcanberra-gtk3-0
            - libcanberra-gtk-module
            - libcanberra-gtk0
            - libcanberra-pulse
            - libcanberra0
            - libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev
            - libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
            - libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386
            - libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you try adding `after: [desktop-gtk3]`? This should pull in a number of things which can be used in gtk3 apps. Use the desktop launcher too as in https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/blob/master/galculator/snapcraft.yaml

Comment: I tried after: [desktop/qt5] after I made this post along with some other things, but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: Does `[desktop-gtk3]` help?

Comment: I think I tried that. I think the [desktop/qt5] included everything that did, but with more. Though for now I've given up.

Comment: You could also try running `snappy-debug.security scanlog` while executing the program and see if there are apparmor denials.